# Индексы, отдельно для каждого поля или в одном

Tags: mysql, индексация, индексы

В чем разница, создавать индекс для каждого поля отдельно и в один индекс напихать несколько полей?
Например, таблица `users`, я знаю, что поле `email` - уникально. Создаю на него индекс `UNIQUE` с именем `UNIQUE email`. У меня есть еще поле логин, которое по сути тоже уникально, что лучше создать для него отдельный `UNIQUE` или добавить в существующий там где `email`? Так же интересует есть ли смысл создавать UNIQUE на `id`, который `PRIMARY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индексы необходимы для оптимизации запросов к БД, причем это нельзя назвать универсальной штукой. То есть, просто понавставлять индексов для каждого поля не принесет абсолютно никакой полезности.

Индексы строятся на основе запросов. Соответственно, Вы смотрите какие запросы у Вас используются наиболее часто или какие запросы наиболее "тяжелые", в общем именно те запросы, которые и грузят.

Например это запрос `SELECT * FROM NEWS_TABLE WHERE DATE = NOW()` - допустим он используется чрезвычайно регулярно и всеми (Новости), чтобы облегчить этот запрос достаточно использовать лишь индекс DATE. Однако, если модифицировать этот запрос на `SELECT * FROM NEWS_TABLE WHERE DATE = NOW() AND CATEGORY = 'Politics'`, который будет использован не менее часто, то для него имеет смысл организовать связный индекс для `DATE и CATEGORY`, во втором случае будет лучше работать именно индекс `DATE, CATEGORY`, чем один индекс `DATE` или 2 несвязных индекса `DATE` и `CATEGORY`, то же самое относится и к другим операторам SQL запросов.

По поводу unique полей, тут все аналогично, все зависит от того, что именно Вам нужно. Если важно, чтобы в базе был один единственный Киркоров Филипп Бедросович (или любая другая комбинация ФИО), а данные хранятся в разных полях `Secondname`, `Name`, `Surname`, то Unique нужно задавать сразу для всех 3х полей одновременно, а не для каждого по отдельности. Если Вы создадите 3 отдельных Unique поля в данном случае, то на всю базу у Вас будет 1 Киркоров, 1 Филипп, 1 Бедросович.

`Primary` изначально уникальный, поэтому смысла нет.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы понять, как работают индексы, полезно рассмотреть такую штуку, как телефонный справочник. В наше время практически не встречается, тем не менее, представление о нём есть почти у всех.

В телефонном справочнике перечислены абоненты, отсортированные сначала по фамилии, затем по имени.

- АНДРЕЕВ ИЛЬЯ, 22-31-97
- АНДРЕЕВА МАРИЯ, 22-45-11
- АНДРЕЕВ ПЁТР, 22-94-34

Вот три записи, а представим, что таких записей 100000. Сложно ли найти, где появляется первый Андреев? Нет: поскольку строки расположены в алфавитном порядке по фамилии. Выбрав произвольную запись мы быстро понимаем, до или после неё находится наша запись. Обычный двоичный поиск.

А сложно ли найти, где появляется первый Эммануил? Очень сложно, быстрого способа не существует. Нам придётся искать подряд с самого начала. И если Эммануила в данном городе не проживает, мы это узнаем только в самом конце.

А сложно ли найти, где появляется первый Андреев Пётр? Снова просто, потому что при совпадении фамилий справочник упорядочен по именам, значит, Пётр Андреев будет после Ильи Андреева, но раньше Сергея.

Практический вывод отсюда таков: если вам нужен поиск и по фамилии, и по имени, то потребуется два индекса. Условно говоря, потребуется два справочника: в первом телефоны будут упорядочены по фамилии, а во втором по имени.

А вот если нужен поиск по фамилии, или по фамилии и имени (именно в таком порядке), то подойдёт один справочник с составным ключом.

Отдельного разговора заслуживают уникальные индексы. Дело в том, что они не ускоряют поиск, но они обеспечивают целостность данных. Кроме того, уникальные индексы важны для реализации внешних ключей: внешний ключ может указывать только на уникальный индекс в другой таблице.

Поэтому полезно завести уникальные индексы и на поле электронный адрес, и на поле логин. Хотя в наше время лучше от поля логин отказаться и хранить только электронный адрес, иначе получается слишком сложно для пользователей.